# woocommerce display cross sell and up sell before single_product_summary

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

i want to order cross sell and up sell widget before single product summary box.

this is my code:

```html
<script>
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_upsell_display', 15 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'bbloomer_woocommerce_output_upsells', 5 );

function woocommerce_output_upsells() {
woocommerce_upsell_display( 3,3 ); // Display max 3 products, 3 per row
}

remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_cross_sell_display', 15 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'bbloomer_woocommerce_output_cross_sell', 5 );

function woocommerce_output_cross_sell() {
woocommerce_cross_sell_display( 3,3 ); // Display max 3 products, 3 per row
}
</script>
```

upsell is moved up. but cross sell box dont move up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
remove_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_upsell_display', 15);
add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'bbloomer_woocommerce_output_upsells', 5);

function bbloomer_woocommerce_output_upsells() {
    woocommerce_upsell_display(3, 3); // Display max 3 products, 3 per row
}

//remove_action('woocommerce_cart_collaterals', 'woocommerce_cross_sell_display'); // This removes cross sell from cart page
remove_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_cross_sell_display'); // There is no hook like this binded in WooCommerce
add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'bbloomer_woocommerce_output_cross_sell', 5);

function bbloomer_woocommerce_output_cross_sell() {
    woocommerce_cross_sell_display(3, 3); // Display max 3 products, 3 per row
}
```

Please try replacing your code with this.

Comment: I tested this code. But the problem has not been solved

Comment: Have you tried switching the theme with code snippet?